# Reusable CSS Classes or Lots?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Had a question that I've often wondered about. Is it better to have multiple CSS classes that you can use in multiple places across you site i.e.

```
.padding5 {padding:5px;} 
.margin10 {margin:10px;} 
.left {float:left;}
.right {float:right;}
```

So you HTML code looks like this

```
<div class="padding5 left"> ... </div>
```

Or rather have explicit classes for every element. i.e.

```
.title-demo {padding:5px; float:left;}
```

with HTML

```
<div class="title-demo"> ... </div>
```

The obvious advantages of the top organisation are that you save yourself having to repeat CSS over and over and over and your CSS stylesheet is much smaller for larger websites.

Just wondering what's recommended by the gurus out there? My idea is essentially to create a "hybrid" solution which allows common CSS to be included as "padding5" combined with classes etc ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NO! Css class names should be descriptive and contextual. You are locking yourself in a maintaince disaster the way you are describing it. What if the padding of `padding5` become `10px` later? Imagine a class named "blue" that you change the color to red of. You'll end up with a hell of a website to maintain.

I suggest using named parts of your website:

```
 #Agenda {
 }

 #Agenda .Item {
 }

 #Agenda .Item h1 {
 }
```

**UPDATE after all comments:**

what about giving your website parts that have common properties a conceptual name -> `SideBarItem`, `Acticle`, `ItemFooter`, `Widget`. And then any element in your website gets a class for one of the named parts and some additional class. `<div class="Widget WeatherForecast">` and `<div class="Widget CurrencyConverter">` class `Widget` defines the common properties and the other class the specific properties.

```
.Widget {
 padding: 10px;
 float: left;
 margin: 5px;
}

.WeatherForecast {
 background: red;
 color: white;
}

.CurrencyConverter {
 background: blue;
 color: black;
}
```

Comment: sure :) but the point is that padding5 won't change to padding10 ? :) because there is already a padding10 ! etc. the idea is that you can combine the 2 ? i.e. use padding5 where you need it without having to repeat it in every element ?

Comment: @Tom: By that logic you might as well just use `style` attributes everywhere and forgo a stylesheet altogether.

Comment: @Tom , please today make padding10 which actually is 5 pixels of padding into 7 pixels of padding, and you know what, please make it into 7em of padding instead of 10 pixels or 5 pixels or ..... - You'll get my point

Comment: but not really ? if padding5 is a common element across the site. why would I then have to repeat in 50x including the text "padding:5px;" in my CSS ? instead just add another HTML class to the element ?

Comment: sure but lets say I use it 30 times on the site ? the recommendation is to just repeat that 30x inside the CSS for every class instead of adding one CSS class and adding it as a HTML element ?

Comment: @Tom up to the level of semantic contextual class names you can combine what you want to prevent having the same info multiple times in the stylesheet, i.e. `<div class="Widget Agenda List">`. But not up to the level that class names become abstract intangible representations of parts of parts of parts of your website. Then you are just pushing it. :)

Comment: @BoltClock so you're suggesting that CSS size is less important that HTML structure ?

Comment: @Tom: Duh. That's the whole point of CSS: to keep HTML a structural and descriptive language. Not a presentational language.

Comment: i'm learning :) just assumed that abstracting common CSS properties  into individual classes and then adding them as HTML elements was easier than repeating them over and over.

Comment: @Tom, what about giving your website parts that have common properties a conceptual name -> SideBarItem, Acticle, ItemFooter, Widget. And then any element in your website get a class for one of the named parts and some additional class. `<div class="Widget WeatherForecast">` and `<div class="Widget CurrencyConverter">` class Wdiget defines the common properties and the other class the specific properties.

Comment: I agree that precise names like "padding5" is not good but disagree that you should just instead constantly set styles on every specific things. It's useful to have common reusable styles. Instead of "padding5" have something like "pad-small {padding 3}, pad-medium {padding 5}" etc. The values and range will depend on your site style. Then you can reuse these and have consistency throughout your site. Eg "nav div" has medium pad, "main content" also has medium pad, etc

Answer (score 1):

Definitely the later.  a class like .padding5  really defeats the purpose of moving style declarations into a style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS the way you suggest is similar to inline styling (actually you're just wrapping the inline styles in a CSS class). So the short answer is: do not use it like that.

Like BoltClock says, there's no harm in defining padding in a few meaningful classes. The best practice is to move *common* styles to their own classes, but you should be reasonable when defining these common styles: only a definition of padding shouldn't exist as a class on its own.

Your second proposal is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

One place where style-based class names can be useful is if you have a fairly complicated set of styles that you want to apply to a lot of different things.

CSS grid systems (e.g. http://960.gs) do this, because their styles are reasonably complicated (especially when fixes for Internet Explorer are taken into account), and they’re designed to be applied to a lot of different elements.

If they didn’t use style-based class names, you’d need to either repeat the style rules from the class in several different places in your stylesheet, or stack all the selectors for the elements that want to use that style above it, neither of which are particularly easy to work with, maintenance-wise.

But in general, CSS styles are designed to be simple enough that you don’t need to encapsulate a set of them.